# python + parse.com upload data if broken internet connection

Tags: python, connection, httprequest, parse-platform

I use a script with an infinite loop to upload sensor data to parse.com. I use

```
batcher.batch_save(myDataPoints)
```

to upload the data. 
The problem is if the computer where the script runs (a raspberry pi) looses the internet connection, the scipt will exit on an error because the batcher can't reach the parse api.

how can I avoid this? If there is no internet connection, I would like the program to execute some code and keep looping, but NOT to exit on an error.

thanks.

Comment: I think this is really interesting.I see a really complex problem you really need two infinite loops I think that tie back together.  First you have to have a loop 'while connection good' and then you have to have a loop 'while connection bad' and then you have to move back and forth between them seamlessly.  So you have to queue the data in some type of burst and test to see if the burst made it through.  The problem is restarting the connection.  Sorry for the stream of consciousness here.  What do you mean by execute some code - do you want it to spin in anticipation of the connection?

Comment: Okay I think I am getting my head around this - you need a little bit of recursiveness.  So your upload function operates until it does not and then the spinner spins until the connection is reestablished and when the connection is fixed you go back to the batcher.  The problem I see is how can you keep track of what was uploaded and what was not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to keep going after you get an error you can just use try...except, e.g.

```
while True:
    try:
        upload_function()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

This should catch your exception and instead of exiting out of your while loop, just continue on. You can put whatever you want to do there, you don't have to just leave it as pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
def spinner(newList):
    count = 0
    while connection_is_bad:
        count +=1
    x= uploader(newList)
```

If your data is a list I think it gets easier

```
def uploader(someList):
    last_value = ''
    while connection_is_good:
        for item in someList:
            do some uploading
            last_value = item

        return something
    newList = someList[someList.index(last_value) + 1:]
    x = spinner(newList)
```

Here is my thought about some pseudo-code.  I can imagine a number of ways to keep track of the data being transferred but not completely sure until I saw how it was collected